# MySQL: Something wrong with Fulltext search - Returning NO results

Tags: mysql

I have a table `places(name  vachar(50), address text, description text) engine = MYISAM` and few records.

I have been trying to do some example in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)!, and searching for the 'full-text problem'  but i have not clear about fulltext search.

First, i add a fulltext index by:

```
ALTER TABLE places ADD FULLTEXT(name, address, description);
```

and try mySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE MATCH(name,address,description) AGAINST('my search key');
```

i have try some 'my search key' that content is in many field, but there are some case i got:

- now row selected .
- if  i trying `add option "IN BOOLEAN MODE" in AGAINST()`, result obtained with score =1 , its is meaningless when i  sort it .
- it just show the result when the "search key" has content in field (name).

i tried a lot way but i don't remember all cases,

Any answer could help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your key word? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: thank Marcus, my problem in search key with stop_word, and default ft_min_word_len.

Comment: Cool. I updated your question title to clarify and added an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ensure that your key word is not a [stop word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). To [disable or modify the stop word list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file), you'll need access to set system variables and restart the server.

Also, ensure that your key word meets the [minimum full text word length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len). The default minimum length is 4.

Finally, ensure that the word appears in less than 50% of the records. MySQL won't return results where the word appears in 50% or more of the records.

Comment: O.M.G.!!! I've been testing for an hour on a 2-record table.  @*&$#%^$%!   +9001    - and no I don't see the word `percent` `%` in the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: N.B. The 50% limitation is MyISAM-specific and does not apply to InnoDB.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Marcus' answer:

When I first started with FULLTEXT indexes in MySQL, I had problems with empty results - I was avoiding stop words and was also using long enough ones, so I was head-scratching a bit until I found this buried in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html):

> The 50% threshold has a significant implication when you first try full-text searching to see how it works: If you create a table and insert only one or two rows of text into it, every word in the text occurs in at least 50% of the rows. As a result, no search returns any results. Be sure to insert at least three rows, and preferably many more. Users who need to bypass the 50% limitation can use the boolean search mode

This also explains why you got results (but with a "meaningless" score) when you set the query to operate IN BOOLEAN MODE

Comment: +1 for being the one who found this.  And kudos for pointing out the highly obscure documentation location.  Although I swear to all that is still Oracle that boolean mode wasn't working either until **after** I read this page.  But maybe that was just my propensity to search for things like `foo` initially...  I mean c'mon, my LAST NAME is 3 letters.

Comment: Woow You are aweome I falled in love with you :) adding a +1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the query was working in the past and suddenly my tests started failing. I managed to isolate the query and indeed, it didn't returned any results. I was using `boolean mode` so the 50% rule could not have caused the issue.

I solved the issue by running:

```sql
OPTIMIZE TABLE organizations; # replace table name
```

I think sometimes the MySQL index stops working when you have a lot of writes / deletes. Weird that I didn't got an error instead.