# MySQL - full text search can't work with certain search term

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, full-text-search

I got a query like this

```
$against = $this->input->get('search');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM news  WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('{$against}') ");
```

And my news table is like this:

```
id | title 
1  | epic cat dog
```

if search term is "cat", row return is 0

search term is "dog", row return is 0

search term is "epic", row return is 1

search term is "epic cat dog", row return is 1

What wrong with the word "cat" and "dog" that mysql won't consider them as result?

Comment: probably here answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523390/mysql-something-wrong-with-fulltext-search-returning-no-results `The default minimum length is 4.`

Comment: otherwise you can use %LIKE% statement

Comment: why do you use LIKE?

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523390/mysql-something-wrong-with-fulltext-search-returning-no-results