# Why does my MYSQL fulltext search yield zero results?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a mysql table with a column named 'country'. I have several other columns as well and all those columns, including 'country' have fulltext index. Everything works fine for all the columns. But there is a problem implementing fulltext search with 'country'. Actually, all the records have the same country (say, 'ABC'), and running this query yields 0 results:

select * from table where match(country) against ('ABC');

All my records have the same country 'ABC'. So, is the empty return set the result of all the records having the same relevance? Or am I making some mistake?
Thanks

Comment: ON both innodb and myisam there is a parameter where it is specified the minimum length of the word searched,the default is 4 I think,so ABC is ignored.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but 'ABC' was just an example. The country I was searching for was of 7 letters.

Comment: Show some sample data,the real query and the table definition for a more exact answer

Comment: @Mihai I found a thread that seems to provide a valid answer. For search to be successful, the search phrase must be in less than 50% of the records. Here's the link to the same:
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523390/mysql-something-wrong-with-fulltext-search-returning-no-results)
Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Put it as your own answer and accept it in 2 days or wahtever

Comment: No, this is a duplicate question and should be closed or removed altogether.